# Showing block confirmations on a user transaction, best practices?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, blocks, confirmations

I'm working on a site that allows users to deploy smart contracts via MetaMask. Basically they customize it, it gets compiled, and then the user deploys it by via a MetaMask transaction.

I would like to show this newly created contract on a page, where other users can click and interact with it. However, I'm unsure of what the best practices are when displaying newly created contracts from the blockchain.

Should I display a confirmation count beside the contract? Should interaction buttons be be greyed out / inaccessible for other users until we have enough confirmations? Should we not show the contract until we have enough confirmations? Any opinions on these tradeoffs is appreciated.